# jquery breaking another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a datepicker which came deafult with a html template , everything worked fine untill i used a custom jquery to hide a div using a radio button ...

here are my top scripts

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/globalize.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js'></script>     
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/actions.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/charts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/settings.js'></script>
```

if i use this then datepicker is working fine but my jquery is not working , my jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#vodn").trigger("click");
        $('#div1').hide('fast');
        $('#vod').click(function () {
            $('#div2').hide('fast');
            $('#div1').show('fast');
        });
        $('#vodn').click(function () {
            $('#div1').hide('fast');
            $('#div2').show('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

my jquery is only working if i call this jquery.min.js before my jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

BUT the problem is then my custom jquery is working but datepicker is not working (may be because i am calling jquery.min.js twice) , what mistake am i doing and how to correct it ...

**EDIT** : i observed that when i use noconflict the place where i import the jquery.min.js is affecting the page , if i import it before js/plugins.js then my date picker is not working and if i import it after plugins.js then my custom code is not working

Comment: What about placing your own `<script>` tag and custom code below all the other script tags? And removing the second `jquery.min` script?

Comment: nope not working , datepicker is working but my custom code is not working

Comment: Not enough info, no demo, no error log; voting to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add noConflict on very first line of your jquery script

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#vodn").trigger("click");
    $('#div1').hide('fast');
    $('#vod').click(function () {
        $('#div2').hide('fast');
        $('#div1').show('fast');
    });
    $('#vodn').click(function () {
        $('#div1').hide('fast');
        $('#div2').show('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: nope not working , one thing i observed is that when i use noconflict the place where i import the jquery is affecting the page , if i import it before js/plugins.js then my date picker is not working and if i import it after plugins.js then my custom code is not working

Answer (score 0):

your jquery files are conflicting. Try doing the following:

```
var j = $.noConflict();
```

then you initialize your datepicker through the variable `j`.

For example.

```
j("#your-selector").datepicker();
```

Comment: Nope no luck , can you plz tell me how to do it for my custom js , i mean using no conflict

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to pass the jQuery object by name and then use the `$` inside:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   ...
});
```

Also, you may want to migrate right after your you load jQuery and if that doesn't work, you should post what error is being displayed in your console.

We cannot magically ascertain what script you haven't shown (html and not) is problematic. It could be your use of vod/vodn to refer to a non-existing element.